# Difference between e.X and MousePosition.X during a MouseDown event?

Tags: .net, mouseevent, mousedown

I've got a MouseDown event on a GridControl that determines which row the user clicked on:

```
    private void genericView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var hitInfo = vw.CalcHitInfo(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        //do other things with the hitInfo object
    }
```

This code works just as I'd expect it to.

However, this code does not

```
    private void genericView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var hitInfo = vw.CalcHitInfo(new Point(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y));
        //do other things with the hitInfo object
    }
```

It compiles, but returns inaccurate data.

I would think that the MouseEventArgs and the MousePosition would be the same coordinate, but I guess not. What's different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e.X` and `e.Y` are relative to the control, while `MousePosition` are relative to the `Screen.Bounds`.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. On the MosueEventArgs page it simply describes X/Y as `Gets the x/y-coordinate of the mouse during the generating mouse event.` Weird that it doesn't specify control relativity.

Comment: sorry-- Have to wait a period of time before I can accept something as an answer, then had to go to a meeting.